# Problema com altura de linha em uma tabela no HTML

Tags: html, table

Usei o seguinte código para mostrar alguns dados em uma tabela:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr  heigth="2px">
            <th  align="left" width="180">Nr DBC</th>
            <th align="left" width="380px">Descrição DCB</th>
            <th align="left" width="400px">Medicamento / Apresentação</th>
            <th align="left" width="80">Estoque &#013 Inicial</th>
            <th align="left" width="80">Entrada&#013 (Aquisição)</th>
            <th align="left" width="80">Saida &#013(Receitas)</th>
            <th align="left" width="80">Perda</th>
            <th align="left" width="80">Estoque &#013 Final</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr heigth="5px" ng-repeat="item in lstMov" class="small">
            <td height="5px"><h6>{{ item.dcb_substancia }}</h6></></td>
            <td height="5px"><h6>{{ item.nome_substancia }}</h6></td>
            <td height="5px"><h6>{{ item.nome_medicamento }}</h6></td>
            <td height="5px" align="center"><h6>{{ item.estoque_anterior }}</h6></td>
            <td height="5px" align="center"><h6>{{ item.qtde_entrada }}</h6></td>
            <td height="5px" align="center"><h6>{{ item.qtde_saida }}</h6></td>
            <td height="5px" align="center"><h6>{{ item.qtde_perda }}</h6></td>
            <td height="5px" align="center"><h6>{{ item.estoque }}</h6></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

O resultado é apresentado na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso diminuir a altura da linha, como podem ver na imagem, está muito alta, no `td` e `tr`, atribui `heigth="5px"`, mas não surtiu efeito.

Como posso alterar a altura da linha? Estou usando esse [template](http://altair_app.tzdthemes.com/#/)

Comment: Não sei se ainda é útil para você essa resposta, mas na declaração da tag <tr> linha 3 e na linha 15, há um erro de grafia no parâmetro height. Você escreveu heigth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria preciso um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável.
Mas até da para entender a tag h1~h6 tem essa formatação espaçada mesmo.

```html
<table border="2">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th  align="left" width="180">Nr DBC</th>
                                <th align="left" width="380px">Descrição DCB</th>
                                <th align="left" width="400px">Medicamento / Apresentação</th>
                                <th align="left" width="80">Estoque &#013 Inicial</th>
                                <th align="left" width="80">Entrada&#013 (Aquisição)</th>
                                <th align="left" width="80">Saida &#013(Receitas)</th>
                                <th align="left" width="80">Perda</th>
                                <th align="left" width="80">Estoque &#013 Final</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="item in lstMov" class="small">
                                <td>{{ item.dcb_substancia }}</></td>
                                <td>{{ item.nome_substancia }}</td>
                                <td>{{ item.nome_medicamento }}</td>
                                <td align="center">{{ item.estoque_anterior }}</td>
                                <td align="center">{{ item.qtde_entrada }}</td>
                                <td align="center">{{ item.qtde_saida }}</td>
                                <td align="center">{{ item.qtde_perda }}</td>
                                <td align="center">{{ item.estoque }}</td>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```